# argv and argc uses with input/output files

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, file-io, command-line-arguments

Suppose I have a code structured as such: Main function - opens a file, searches and grabs the text/numbers to specific variables, then closes. Another file gets opened, searches some more and closes. Then, the code is as follows to implement the argv argc:

```
if (argc >= 5) {
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 1) {
        compare();
    }

    if (atoi(argv[2]) == 2) {
        certainblood();
    }

    if (atoi(argv[3]) == 3) {
        longestpatient();
    }
}
```

So in here, if i were to run program.exe 1, it should display the function and do what the function is supposed to do. then program.exe 2 should do the other function and so on. Why is it that it is not taking my variables and passing them to the function. Its solely running the function. Even if I make a function to open both files and put them in the argv, it still dosent do that function. Why is this the case? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what kind of other parameter your program may use, try out following, leaving out the `argv >= 5` check because in your example you are only giving one parameter (argc == 2):

```
if (atoi(argv[1]) == 1) {
    compare();
}

if (atoi(argv[1]) == 2) {    /* changed argv[2] to argv[1] */
    certainblood();
}

if (atoi(argv[1]) == 3) {    /* changed argv[3] to argv[1] */
    longestpatient();
}
```

`argv[0]` gives back the program name,
`argv[1]` the first parameter,
`argv[2]` the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying to only check the `argv[]` values if there are 4 or more parameters.  Do you really want that argc test there?

And I think you mean to check `argv[1]` in each `if` test (right now you're checking if parm 1 is 1, if parm 2 is 2, ...)

Comment: Yes that is correct, the above example clarifies the concept.

Comment: this is extremely close, its just not passing the info from the text to the functions for some odd reason. However, I fully understand how the argv and argc works! thanks!

Comment: You may need to add `argv[1]` to each function parameter.  Or better still set `atoi(argv[1])` to a variable, use that in your tests and as a parameter